# How to implement file sharing for mobile app over wireless network

Tags: php, ios, actionscript-3, air, wireless

I’m developing an app using Adobe Air. I want my users to be able to transfer files from a computer into the internal storage of the mobile app, but over a wireless router.

**Question**:

How to operate like a web server using my AIR app (turn the current smartphone into a web server)? I want run server-side scripts like PHP from device.

When the smart phone and the desktop (Mac/PC) are connected to the same wi-fi network, each one has an IP address like `192.168.1.xxx`. Using the app, a PHP script will handle the file upload operation.

I am open to other (more correct or efficient) methods about transferring files between two devices, since the PHP way might be only solving an `X/Y problem`.

Comment: What is the exact technical problem you're having? Also, as far as you described it, the *wireless* factor is irrelevant, it's just a regular PHP backend available over LAN rather then Internet.

Comment: @Organis I think I describe it so clear! The problem is how my app can run a web server when user taps on Import from computer button. Then if they type the local IP address on pc they see a php script to upload files to the internal storage of the app.

Comment: It is not a **technical** problem. It is something about architecture of client-server solution. The thing you're asking is considered **too broad** and **opinion-based** here on StackOverflow. *You need a device that will run an HTTP-server with PHP-preprocessing enabled. Then you need some PHP-scripts that will handle file uploads and the other backend functionality.* See? Too vague. Too broad.

Comment: @Organis I need my app run Apache server to be able to run php script! Is that too vague or broad?! And why it’s not a technical problem? I have no idea about how doing that and I ask here to see some suggestions. I think it’s better to help instead of defining my kind of problem.

Comment: I agree, this question is much too broad for stackoverflow.  There are many different ways to implement this and many different opinions.  All of which are too involved for the stackoverflow format.  If your app is going to live on both the mobile and desktop,  look into sockets http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis no my app is just gonna live on the smart phone. If the user enters the IP address of the smart phone on the local network, a php script will be displayed. So you say many different ways? Ok, one of those different ways could be the answer! Thanks…

Comment: @ArashDaneshAraste regarding _"..Ok, one of those different ways could be the answer!"_ what? You mean like : [**some basic research**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ios+setup+local+server) ... Which **specific** part of this process are you struggling with? Otherwise point your URL to PHP file saved on the local server (works same like web server but even without internet, so make sure it supports PHP). Do this **while local server is running or enabled** otherwise PHP file won't work (if not opened via server, it's just a text file)

Comment: @VC.One please read my question carefully. The smart phone on the local network is gonna run as a web server and serve the php backend. And it’s not a text file because it’s gonna handle file upload from computer to the app!

Comment: _"The smart phone on the local network is gonna run as a web server"_ so setup using the research links above.... _"it’s not a text file"_ **only if** _"it’s gonna handle file upload"_ while device is in server mode (ie: it's own localhost is available). This way the PHP will actually be processed as a **server-side* script. If you load the url of your PHP and see only source code then you're seeing PHP as text file not as script result.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the [Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) technology (and you won't need any PHP).

Using Cirrus, you can create the functionality that you describe even if the devices are not on the same WiFi network (having in mind both the PC and the mobile device are running AIR applications). AIR is needed on the PC side in order to be able to access the files without user intervention. You won't enter the IP in order to link the PC app with the mobile app, although you'll need to provide the address received from the Cirrus service.

It is not trivial to write and test the apps, but they're definitely doable.

At the link above you should find all the info and resources in order to get started including how to get a [developer key](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=cirrus), [an overview](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/rtmfpgroups.html) of RTMFP Groups and a [sample app](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/).

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I will try it, but don’t you think that by this solution you force the user to run AIR Application on PC device? Many of users don’t like to install it on their PC to be able to share files between mobile an PC. They usually prefer to do this as simplest as it can be done.

Comment: I'm glad you will try it! Actually you can do the file explorer and selection side in a web browser via Flash Player. The downside is that the selection of which files to copy over will have to be made on the desktop, not on the mobile device. Using the AIR mobile to AIR desktop approach you could have the desktop app run in background and be just a proxy for the mobile app to get access to the file system.